# Python and Tweepy: result on CSV file

Tags: python, csv, unicode, tweepy

My code to get the Tweets in a CSV file:

```
csvfile = open('twits.csv','w')
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)

for item in result:
    csvwriter.writerow([unicode(item.user.screen_name).encode("utf-8"),unicode(item.text).encode("utf-8"),item.user.followers_count])
```

The error I get:

```
csvwriter.writerow([unicode(item.user.screen_name).encode("utf-8"),unicode(item.text).encode("utf-8"),item.user.followers_count])
**NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined**
```

How do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Have you imported the `unicode` library?

Comment: They're attempting to use [the Python 2 `unicode` type](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type), not an external `unicode` library or method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Python 3?
[The `unicode` type](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type) is from Python 2 and doesn't exist anymore in Python 3, as [the `str` type itself is now Unicode](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type).

Comment: You should [accept the answer, rather than comment to thank the answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).